# Error: "serving_default not found in signature def" when testing prediction

Tags: prediction, google-cloud-ml, google-ai-platform

I followed this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/algorithms/wide-deep-start#console_3) and came to the point where I can test a prediction using the following code:

```
{
   "instances": [
     {"csv_row": "44, Private, 160323, Some-college, 10, Married-civ-spouse, Machine-op-inspct, Husband, Black, Male, 7688, 0, 40, United-States", "key": "dummy-key"}
   ]
 }
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": "{ \"error\": \"Serving signature name: \\\"serving_default\\\" not found in signature def\" }"
}
```

I presume the input format doesn't represent the expected input, but am not entirely should what should be expected.

Any ideas as to what is causing the example code to throw this error?

Comment: Can you try adding the flag [”--signature-name predict”](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/predict#--signature-name) to your "gcloud ai-platform predict" command? I was able to successfully get predictions from the model.

Comment: its actually as you said Just: --signature-name "predict”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out:  I loaded the tensorflow model in jupyter notebook and printed out the signatures:

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('modelPath')
print(list(new_model.signatures.keys()))
```

the result was: [u'predict']

so the command i used to get a prediction is:

georg@Georgs-MBP ~ % gcloud ai-platform predict 
--model $MODEL_NAME 
--version "v1" 
--json-instances sample_input.json 
--format "value(predictions[0].classes[0])" 
--signature-name "predict"

result:
Using endpoint [https://europe-west3-ml.googleapis.com/]
<=50K

Comment: You need to mark this as the answer since you asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

To add signature serving_default:

```
import tensorflow as tf
m = tf.saved_model.load("tf2-preview_inception_v3_classification_4")
print(m.signatures) # _SignatureMap({}) - Empty
t_spec = tf.TensorSpec([None,None,None,3], tf.float32)
c_func = m.__call__.get_concrete_function(inputs=t_spec)
signatures = {'serving_default': c_func}
tf.saved_model.save(m, 'tf2-preview_inception_v3_classification_5', signatures=signatures)

# Test new model
m5 = tf.saved_model.load("tf2-preview_inception_v3_classification_5")
print(m5.signatures) # _SignatureMap({'serving_default': <ConcreteFunction signature_wrapper(*, inputs) at 0x17316DC50>})
```